# How to prepare Google Natural Language Proscessing output (json) for Big Query

Tags: sql, json, nlp, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to query the output of a Natural Language Processing (NLP) call in Big Query (BQ) but I'm struggling to get the output in the right format for BQ.

I understand that BQ takes json files (as newline delimited) - but just not sure that (a) the output of NLP is json newline delimited and (b) if my schema is correct.

Here's the json output I'm working with:

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "name": "Rowling",
      "type": "PERSON",
      "metadata": {
        "wikipedia_url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._K._Rowling"
      },
      "salience": 0.65751493,
      "mentions": [
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "   J.",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "K. Rowl",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "LONDON",
      "type": "LOCATION",
      "metadata": {
        "wikipedia_url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London"
      },
      "salience": 0.14284456,
      "mentions": [
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "\ufeffLON",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Harry Potter",
      "type": "WORK_OF_ART",
      "metadata": {
        "wikipedia_url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter"
      },
      "salience": 0.0726779,
      "mentions": [
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "th Harry Pot",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "‘Harry Pot",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Deathly Hallows",
      "type": "WORK_OF_ART",
      "metadata": {
        "wikipedia_url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Deathly_Hallows"
      },
      "salience": 0.022565609,
      "mentions": [
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "he Deathly Hall",
            "beginOffset": -1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "language": "en"
}
```

Is there a way to send the output directly to big query via the command line in Google Cloud shell?

Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad you found my Harry Potter blog post! I'd recommend storing the NL API's JSON response as a string in BigQuery and then using a [user-defined function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions) to query it. You should be able to run the following (the table is publicly viewable) to get a count of how often each entity appears in the JSON you posted:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) as entity_count, entity
FROM 
  JS(
    (SELECT entities FROM [sara-bigquery:samples.hp_udf]),
    entities,
    "[{ name: 'entity', type: 'string'}]",
    "function(row, emit) { 
      try {
        x = JSON.parse(row.entities);
        entities = x['entities'];
        entities.forEach(function(data) {
          emit({ entity: data.name });
        });
      } catch (e) {}
    }" 
  )
GROUP BY entity
ORDER BY entity_count DESC
```

Comment: This isn't what I would recommend. The preferred way to read the output from a JSON payload would be using `JSON_EXTRACT` or `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` using legacy or (preferably) standard SQL, since this will be cheaper and faster than using a UDF.

Comment: This works great! Thanks Sara :) Going to have a play with this and report back with findings..

Comment: Sara - Everything's working great via the command line in Google Cloud Shell, but is it possible to implement the same idea via Google Apps Scripts? Essentially I want to call the NLP API and run entity extraction on text within individual cells in a spreadsheet. I'm currently researching it but would be good to know if this is possible first! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> send the output directly to big query via the command line in Google Cloud shell

Look at this page, and search for "bq load"
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool

Here they have some example about json schema.
[Schema to load json data to google big query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623490/schema-to-load-json-data-to-google-big-query)

Comment: I've tried this but the NLP output isn't json newline delimited, as required by BQ - is there a quick and easy way to convert it?