# Can a field have mode NULLABLE and REPEATED in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Can a field in BigQuery have NULLABLE **and** REPEATED mode? For example to represent an array of strings, where some strings might be NULL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To represent an array with NULLABLE elements, you can use a structure to wrap them. For example, you could have a column such as:

```
nullable_arr ARRAY<STRUCT<value INT64>>
```

Taking things a step further, you can represent a possibly-null array with possibly-null elements using another level of indirection:

```
nullable_arr STRUCT<value ARRAY<STRUCT<value INT64>>>
```

The downside, of course, is that it takes more syntax to query. If you wanted to get the sum of the elements in the array defined with the latter type, you would have to do something like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(elem.value) FROM UNNEST(nullable_arr.value) AS elem) AS array_sum
FROM MyTable;
```

For the sake of comparison, taking the sum of a column named `arr` defined as an `ARRAY<INT64>` can be expressed as:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(elem) FROM UNNEST(arr) AS elem) AS array_sum
FROM MyTable;
```

Answer (score 9):

> Can a field in BigQuery have NULLABLE and REPEATED mode?

Nope. Either one or another

> ```
> ARRAYs cannot be NULL.   
> NULL ARRAY elements cannot persist to a table.
> ```

See more in [Data Types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types)

> For example to represent an array of strings, where some strings might be NULL.

Simple example below shows that `Array cannot have a null element;`

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH test AS (
  SELECT ['abc', NULL, 'xyz']  
)
SELECT *
FROM test
```